# implement callback in C++

Tags: c++

I want to be able to implement a function that will be called by another function within a class, like a callback.

for example, we have this prototype:

```
using func = void(__stdcall*)(int val);
```

then i define it inside a class:

```
func * _func;
```

then i implement it in the main file:

```
void __stdcall my_func(int val) { }
...
int main() {
...
myclass._func = &my_func;
```

then, from within another function, I call it:

```
myclass::func_call() {
...
int a = 0;
this._func(a);
```

so i am able to catch every value outside of the class.

how could i do this?

Comment: *"so i am able to catch every value outside of the class"* - can you elaborate on this?

Comment: well, in my project, i have a running thread that continuously provides me with some values i need, but instead of jumping trough hoops to get the values from within the thread, i want a callback to be called with those numbers so i could work with those values from outside of the class that actually produces them

Comment: `func * _func;` this is wrong, `func` is already a pointer, so `func _func;` whould be sufficient.

Comment: You have already done **this**. So what are you asking for exactly?

Comment: The best way to do it in C++ is to define an interface (abstract class) and then provide an implementation.

Comment: @Slava That did it! Thank you! #eerorika The code in the OP is not actually functional #DmitryKuzminov i already fixed my problem but i'm interested in what you mean by "abstract class"? I know you can do such in c# but never saw it done in c++

Comment: Related: [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

Answer (score 2):

The native and idiomatic way to do that in C++ is the virtual function:

```
//using func = void(__stdcall*)(int val);
struct Interface
{
    virtual void func(int val) = 0;
};
```

> then i define it inside a class:

```
//func * _func;
class Implementation : public Interface
{
    void func(int val) final;
};
```

> then i implement it in the main file:

```
class Client
{
public:
    Client(Interface &interface) : interface(interface) {}
    void func_call()
    {
        int a = 0;
        interface.func(a);
    }
private:
    Interface &interface;
};
```

Comment: This is only one of the way doing it in C++. Using `std::function` would be less verbose I believe

Comment: I agree that there are other ways, but for the task described by the author (IMHO) this one is the most idiomatic. And I agree wit @PhilBrubaker that this is called an *Observer*.